# Как сделать нижние элементы видимыми после прокрутки ListView

Tags: android, listview

Есть layout в котором есть список, и элементы которые должны быть видны только после того как список будет прокручен до конца. Пробыл это делать с ScrollView но он поддерживает только один дочерний элемент, что усложняет верстку внутренних элементов, может есть какой то альтернативный способ?

Если нужен какой то дополнительный код, говорите -  я добавлю!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/header_button_shape_baground"
        >

        <Button
            android:text="НАЧАТЬ"
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="4.0sp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/singUpFacebook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="97dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_shape_baground"
            android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayoutInviteFacebook"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitleFacebook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Привязаться к аккаунту Facebook"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDescriptionFacebook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="Что бы сохранить свои покупки  в случае смены телефоны"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewTitleFacebook"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebookImageView"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/facebookImageView" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/facebookImageView"
                android:src="@drawable/facebook"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewTitleFacebook"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="133.5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutInviteFacebook"
            android:background="@drawable/item_shape_baground"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inviteFriendsTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Пригласите 10 друзей и получите бонус"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonInviteFriends"
                android:layout_width="287.5dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/inviteFriendsTextView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_baground"
                android:text="Пригласить друей"
                android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Privacy policy | Support"
                android:id="@+id/textViewFooterTitle"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="2015"
                android:id="@+id/textViewDescriptionFooter"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewFooterTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:textSize="15.5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется footer. [Вот](http://startandroid.ru/en/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/114-urok-55-header-i-footer-v-spiskah-headerviewlistadapter) пример как его применять. Хотя я бы посоветовал разобраться с RecyclerView и ViewHolder так как в нем подобные штуки делаются намного проще.